# list of changed files with author name in last n days

Tags: git

I can get list of changed files in last x days with these commands:

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-status --since="2 days ago"
OR
git whatchanged --since '2 days ago' --oneline --name-only --pretty=format: | sort >> changedlist.txt
```

it only returns name  of changed files, something like:

```
file1.php
file2.php
```

How can i get author name of each file, like:

```
file1.php nameOfauthor
file2.php nameOfauthor
```

*I only want to get file name and author name without extra details.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How it's could be done with `git log`:

```
git log --pretty="" --name-only --since=2d | sort | uniq | xargs -I{} sh -c 'echo "{}|`git log -1 --pretty=%cn -- {}`"' | column -t -s'|'
```

Works also in Git Bash under Windows:

```
$ git log --pretty="" --name-only --since=2d | sort | uniq | xargs -I{} sh -c 'echo "{}|`git log -1 --pretty=%cn -- {}`"' | column -t -s'|'
OpenCart/catalog/controller/account/favorites.php                      Twist
OpenCart/catalog/controller/external/coupons.php                       Twist
OpenCart/catalog/controller/feed/miniset.php                           andrewsmirnov
OpenCart/catalog/controller/landing/coupon_page.php                    George Barlukov
OpenCart/catalog/controller/x.php                                      George Barlukov
OpenCart/catalog/model/design/banner.php                               Twist
composer.json                                                          Twist
gulp/common/filter-locale-files.mjs                                    over_ilaj
gulp/common/gulp-common.mjs                                            over_ilaj
gulp/templates-build.task.mjs                                          over_ilaj
src/img/promo/funko/funko-mob.png                                      Natalia Baganova
src/img/promo/funko/funko.png                                          Natalia Baganova
src/sass/layout/home/_intro-block.scss                                 Natalia Baganova
src/sass/promo/_funko-banner.scss                                      Natalia Baganova
src/sass/style.scss                                                    Natalia Baganova
src/tpl/information/contact.am.twig                                    over_ilaj
src/tpl/product/grid.twig                                              Twist
src/tpl/product/product_tabs.twig                                      George Barlukov
src/tpl/product/stock_block.twig                                       George Barlukov
src/tpl/promo/funko_banner.twig                                        Natalia Baganova
src/tpl/promo/hw22_banner.twig                                         Natalia Baganova
src/tpl/promo/promo_banner.twig                                        Natalia Baganova
twig-check.php                                                         Twist
www/assets/js/checkout/app/modules/favorites.js                        Twist
www/assets/js/checkout/app/nls/interface.js                            George Barlukov
www/assets/js/checkout/app/templates/cart.ejs                          George Barlukov
www/assets/js/checkout/app/templates/delivery/DigitalDistribution.ejs  George Barlukov
www/assets/js/checkout/app/views/GroupView.js                          George Barlukov
```

Comment: any idea to achieve this on windows?

Comment: @MohammadSalehi works in git bash. if you find my answer useful don't forget to accept and upvote it, thanks

Comment: @MohammadSalehi fixed the sorting

Comment: I was using VS code terminal, woked on git bash, thanks.